# Sum Random Value All by One SQL

Tags: sql, sum

I have a table. For example purposes, consider just like this:

```
id       bl         pat       total
 1     052020        2C         -5
 2     052020        2C         10
 3     052020        2C         10
 4     052020        2C        -35
 5     062020        2C         10
 6     062020        2C        -16
```

One thing that I want to do is sum total where bl `052020` and pat `2C`. But everything I do with this kind of SUM was so confused me.

I expected my total value should be -25 but with this SUM I have 60.

Here it is my code:

```
select sum(total) from tb_gas where bl='052020' and pat='2C'
```

How could make it just real total (i mean, it should be like -5 + (10) + 10 + (-35) = -20 )

Is there any suggestion, how to make as I expected?

Thanks.

Comment: The sum of the data you actually showed above is _neither_ of  -25 or 60, it is `-26`.

Comment: I'm baffled:  `-35 + -5 + 10 + 10` is `-20`.  Nothing in your sample data will add up to 60.

Comment: The sum should  be -20. Not -25.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? And are the table's details? [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS and add the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the **data-type** of total?

Answer (score 0):

Could this help you solve your problem?

```
select bl,pat,sum(total) 
from tb_gas 
--where bl='052020' and pat='2C'
group by bl,pat
```